# JavaScript stop scrolling horizontally at the last div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I  am trying to create a carousel like object where you are able to click left and right to view between previous and next images using only HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Here is the code:

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const lefty = document.querySelector(".lefty");
let translate = 0;

lefty.addEventListener("click", function() {
  translate += 200;
  container.style.transform = "translateX(" + translate + "px" + ")";
});

const righty = document.querySelector(".righty");
righty.addEventListener("click", function() {
  translate -= 200;
  container.style.transform = "translateX(" + translate + "px" + ")";
});
```

```css
.outer {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform .4s ease-in;
}

.inner {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.paddle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
}

.lefty {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.righty {
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<button class="lefty paddle" id="left-button"></button>
<div class="outer" id="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner" style="background:red"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:green"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:blue"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:yellow"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:orange"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="righty paddle" id="right-button"></button>
```

The only issue I am having with this is that you can scroll way past the final div color block. Is it possible so that you can't scroll past the first and final div?

CodePen https://codepen.io/laurentkosc1990/pen/eYNXaxG

Comment: Sure, just check the value of `container.style.transform` if the value inside the parentheses is greater than some value, don't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to solving this. In this example I define a max and min value that you can transform and check against that to stop the carousel. Either this can be fixed values or they can be dynamic to let you add and remove inner modules freely.

static

```
let minX = -400
let maxX = 0
```

dynamic

```
//number of inner classes times length, negate the visible classes 
let minX = (inn.length * -200) + 600
```

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const inn = document.getElementsByClassName('inner');
const lefty = document.querySelector(".lefty");
let translate = 0;

//let minX = -400
//number of inner classes times length, negate the visible classes 
let minX = (inn.length * -200) + 600
let maxX = 0

lefty.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(translate >= maxX){
      return;
    }
    translate += 200;
    container.style.transform = "translateX(" + translate + "px" + ")";
});

const righty = document.querySelector(".righty");
righty.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(translate <= minX){
      return;
    }
    translate -= 200;
    container.style.transform = "translateX(" + translate + "px" + ")";
});
```

```css
.outer {

  overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;

}

.container {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform .4s ease-in;
}

.inner {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  height: 100px;
    margin:10px;
}
.paddle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height:20px;
}
.lefty {
    left: 0;
  z-index:1;
}
.righty{
    right: 0;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<button class="lefty paddle" id="left-button"></button>
<div class="outer" id="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner" style="background:red"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:green"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:blue"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:yellow"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:orange"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="righty paddle" id="right-button"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will work for you

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const visibleWidth = container.offsetWidth; // visible width of container
const fullWidth = container.scrollWidth; //width of container incliding hidden part
const innerDivWidth = document.querySelector(".inner").offsetWidth+20;// margin 10px from both sides

const lefty = document.querySelector(".lefty");
let translate = 0;

lefty.addEventListener("click", function() {

  if(translate<0){
    translate += innerDivWidth;
    container.style.transform = "translateX(" + translate + "px" + ")";
  }

});

const righty = document.querySelector(".righty");
righty.addEventListener("click", function() {
  
  //here is my calculation, look carefully, you will get it

 if((translate + fullWidth) > visibleWidth){
   translate -= innerDivWidth;
   container.style.transform = "translateX(" + translate + "px" + ")";
  }

});

// btw translation rate should be according to inner div's width 
// otherwise last div will not show properly
```

```css
.outer {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform .4s ease-in;
}

.inner {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.paddle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
}

.lefty {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.righty {
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<button class="lefty paddle" id="left-button"></button>
<div class="outer" id="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner" style="background:red"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:green"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:blue"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:yellow"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:orange"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="righty paddle" id="right-button"></button>
```